# C# Coping array using a .txt

Tags: c#, arrays, save

Ok... i'm a total novice in the big world of programming.
Said that... i'm having problem with saving\loading one array.

For now i have altready found a way to save a .txt file with the content of the ArrayA.

The result would be a string like this  "0,1,2,3,4"

But i can't find a way to use that .txt file for setting the ArrayB using that file.
i'm totally sure i'm missing something dumb.

However, if someone else know an alternative method i'm very open try to other ways(as long as i can understand them).

EDIT1:

This is the code i have used for creating the savefile.

```
{
FileUtil.DeleteFileOrDirectory(Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/Ordini/" +
 "Ordine" + ".txt");

string txtDocumentname = Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/Ordini/" + 
"Ordine" + ".txt";

        for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
        {
            OrdineArray += ArrayMenù.Array[i] + " ;";
        }


        if (!File.Exists(txtDocumentname))
        {

            File.WriteAllText(txtDocumentname, OrdineArray);
        }

 }
```

Comment: You will need to post what you've attempted. But I would read in the file, Perform a `.Split(',')` and then loop through the char array that `.Split(',')` will give you, and use `Convert.ToInt32()`

Comment: Show how you are saving a .txt file

Comment: If you are just trying to save the array in anyway possible and it doesn't have to be human readable then BinaryFormatter (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter?view=netcore-3.1) is one option. If it has to be human readable, one option is to save it in JSON format (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-overview). They will have examples of serialization and deserialization.

Answer (score 2):

Let's take a step back. There are lots of ways to persist data (of any sort) to a file.

One common and idiomatic approach is to *serialize* it. Once again there are near endless ways to serialize data, however *json* is a great modern serialization solution.

**Advantages**

1. It's easy to read
2. It's easy to do
3. There is a wealth of information on the libraries.
4. It can cater for a plethora of complex custom types.

**Links**

- The *nuget* for Newtonsoft.Json https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/
- The documentation https://www.newtonsoft.com/json

**Install**

```
Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json -Version 12.0.3
```

**Example**

```
var array = new[] {12, 3, 4, 5};

// serialize it
var stringData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(array);

// write to file
File.WriteAllText("FileName", stringData);

// read from file
var dataFromFile = File.ReadAllText("FileName");

// convert it back
var yourArrayAgain = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string[]>(dataFromFile);

// prove it
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", yourArrayAgain));
```

**Output**

```
12,3,4,5
```

[**Contrived online demo here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/UNYFBo)

Answer (score 1):

First you need to read the file

```
string text = File.ReadAllText(txtDocumentname);
```

Then split it into substrings, based on your delimiter:

```
string[] fields = text.Split(';');
```

Then convert the fields into integers:

```
int[] integers = fields.Select( x => int.Parse(x) ).ToArray();
```